# SQL MAX date based on criteria group by item

Tags: sql

| Item | Date | Status Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WidgetA | 2022-01-03 | 1 |
| WidgetB | 2022-01-04 | 1 |
| WidgetA | 2022-01-05 | 2 |
| WidgetB | 2022-01-06 | 2 |
| WidgetA | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| WidgetB | 2022-01-01 | 1 |

I want to group by Item and have min(date) where status = 1 and max(date) where status = 2

| Item | start | complete |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WidgetA | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-05 |
| WidgetB | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-06 |

Not sure where to start here.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and tag your database

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation

`min()` to get the start date and `max()` to get the complete date

```
select Item,
       min(case when status = 1 then Date end) as start,
       max(case when status = 2 then Date end) as complete
from mytable
group by Item
```

This code works on major databases such as `mysql` and `postgresql`...

[Demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/nFI_r51p)